# Should key go to the real HTML element or to my own Component?

Tags: reactjs, preact

```js
var MyComponent = props => {
    return <div key={ props.item.id }>{ props.item.title }</div> // key must be here?
}

myarray.map(item => <MyComponent key={ item.id } item={ item }>) // or here?
```

how to properly use the `key` attribute? By adding to my own component or to the underlying `<div>` element?

Comment: The second one, to the component

Comment: @Omer no, that is wrong. Check out the official docs where they say the opposite: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it should go in mapping function and not directly on div. You want keys to be used by React and not be rendered inside your DOM. So, I suggest not putting them on div, but on MyComponent directly.

Check out the official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are rendering an array of elements or components :

> A good rule of thumb is that elements inside the map() call need keys.

[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys)